# How to update the custom field using soql with limit?

Tags: visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

I have to update Description__c field in Account object where BusinessUnit__c having BU1 to BU1000. I have the records BusinessUnit__c field contains BU1 to BU2000. I need to update Description field from BU1 to BU1000. How can you write the Query for this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? This forum is generally designed to assist folks who demonstrate their progress to date. Please edit your post with same SOQL that you have written

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, Below is the code for that...

```
List<Account> lstacc=[select id,name,Business_Unit__c from Account 
                       where Business_Unit__c like 'BU%' limit 1000 offset 0];
for(Account acc:lstacc){
    acc.Description__c='xyz';
}
update lstacc;
```